# javascript how to normlize array into the proper format json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array which looks like this

```
var arr =  [ [{a:1}],
             [{b:1}],
             [{c:1}], 
             [{d:1}],
             [{e:1}] ]
```

what i want to do is to create a proper format out of it like this

```
 [{a:1},{b:1},{c:1},{d:1},{e:1}]
```

tried many sources and not able to find the best solution

Can anyone help ?

Comment: How would you determine the “best” solution? It looks like you probably want to use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) or a shim for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you (Not ideal but it works)

```
var arr =  [ [{a:1}],
             [{b:1}],
             [{c:1}], 
             [{d:1}],
             [{e:1}] ];
//this is not ideal but it works for u
for (var i = 0; i <arr.length - 1; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i][0];
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
const res = arr.flat()
```

or :

```js
const arr = [ [{ a:1 }], [{b: 1}], [{c:1}], [{d:1}], [{e:1}] ] 

const res = arr.map(([o])=> ({...o})) // for a copy of objects

console.log( JSON.stringify( res ))
```

or : (without makking a new array)

```js
const arr = [ [{ a:1 }], [{b: 1}], [{c:1}], [{d:1}], [{e:1}] ] 

arr.forEach(([o],i,a)=>a[i]=o)

console.log( JSON.stringify( arr ))
```